# ¿Cómo arreglar este error: debe ser declarado?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Esta es una función para calcular el tiempo que un requerimiento dura pausado en un periodo de tiempo determinado, tomando en cuenta varios parámetros entre ellos, hacer el cálculo registro por registro.

Específicamente en donde está arrojando error es en la parte del `busca_ordenes_pediente(wprogramer_code, WFECHA_INICIO)`, dice que debe de *estar declarado*

> Este es el código de la creación de la función:

```
create or replace FUNCTION CALC_HORAS_PAUSA (wprogramer_code varchar2,wprimera_fecha 
 date,wfecha2 date) return number is
 W_ULTIMA_FECHA_INICIO DATE;
 W_ULTIMA_FECHA_FIN DATE;
 WFECHA_MIN_HORARIO  VARCHAR2(20);  
 WHORA_MIN_HORARIO   VARCHAR2(20);  
 WFECHA_HORARIOS_MIN VARCHAR2(20);  
 WFECHA_MAX_HORARIO  VARCHAR2(20);  
 WHORA_MAX_HORARIO   VARCHAR2(20);  
 WFECHA_HORARIOS_MAX VARCHAR2(20);
 WFECHA_INICIO  date;
 WFECHA_fin     date;
 W_TOTAL  NUMBER :=0 ;
 T_ORD_ABIERTA NUMBER; 
 T_ORD_cerrada NUMBER;
 W_HORAS_SIN_ORDENES NUMBER :=0;
 WFECHA_FIN_ACTUAL   date;
 wmin_max_fecha_mes date;
 wmax_max_fecha_mes date;
 xxx date;
 WQUEDAN NUMBER;
```

> El código de *Primer cursor*

```
CURSOR C1 IS 
      SELECT 
      max(A.FECHA_HORA_INICIO) FECHA_INICIO,
      max(NVL(A.FECHA_HORA_FIN,SYSDATE))  FECHA_FIN
  
      FROM 
      TABLE1 A, TABLE2 B,TABLE3 C
   
       WHERE 
       A.NO_ORDEN = B.NO_ORDEN
       AND   B.RUTEAR_A_INITIALS = C.USER_INITIALS
       AND   NVL(C.IND_ASIGNACION,'N')='S'
       AND   B.PROGRAMER_CODE = wprogramer_code
       AND   A.FECHA_HORA_FIN <= wprimera_fecha
       AND   A.ROWID <> A.ROWID 
       AND   (wprimera_fecha BETWEEN  TO_CHAR(A.FECHA_HORA_INICIO,'yyyymm') AND         
        TO_CHAR(A.FECHA_HORA_FIN,'yyyymm')
          OR B.STATUS IN('PAUSADA','EN PROCESO'))
 
      order by A.FECHA_HORA_INICIO, A.FECHA_HORA_FIN;
```

> El código de *Segundo cursor*

```
 cursor c_max_min(p_codigo varchar2) is
        select  max(a.FECHA) fecha_max,
                min(a.FECHA) fecha_min
            from horarios_computos a
        where  CODIGO=p_codigo
         and  FECHA BETWEEN wprimera_fecha AND wfecha2;
```

> El código de *Tercer cursor*

```
cursor c_horarios(p_fecha VARCHAR2,p_codigo varchar2) is 
    select 
        CODIGO,
      to_CHAR(FECHA,'DD-MM-YYYY') FECHA,
        HORA_INI_M,
    DECODE(nvl(HORA_FIN_T,'00:00'),'00:00',HORA_FIN_M,HORA_FIN_T) AS HORA_FIN_T
    from horarios_computos
    where CODIGO=p_codigo
    and  FECHA = p_fecha;
```

> El código de *Cuarto cursor*

```
cursor c_busca_max_fercha is
    SELECT max(TO_DATE(to_char(A.FECHA_INICIO,'DD-MM-YYYY')||A.HORA_INICIO,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')) FECHA_INICIO,
       max(TO_DATE(to_char(NVL(A.FECHA_FIN,SYSDATE),'DD-MM-YYYY')||NVL(A.HORA_FIN,TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'HH24:MI')),'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')) FECHA_FIN
       FROM TABLE1 A, TABLE2 B,TABLE3 C
       WHERE A.NO_ORDEN = B.NO_ORDEN
     AND   B.RUTEAR_A_INITIALS = C.USER_INITIALS
       AND   NVL(C.IND_ASIGNACION,'N')='S'
       AND   B.PROGRAMER_CODE =wprogramer_code
       AND   (wprimera_fecha BETWEEN  TO_CHAR(A.FECHA_HORA_INICIO,'yyyymm') AND     
     TO_CHAR(A.FECHA_HORA_FIN,'yyyymm')
       OR B.STATUS IN('PAUSADA','EN PROCESO'))
      order by A.FECHA_HORA_INICIO, A.FECHA_HORA_FIN;
```

> El código de *Quinto cursor*

```
 CURSOR C_QUEDAN_ORDENES IS 
          SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM TABLE1 A, TABLE2 B,TABLE3 C
           WHERE A.NO_ORDEN = B.NO_ORDEN
         AND   B.RUTEAR_A_INITIALS = C.USER_INITIALS
         AND   NVL(C.IND_ASIGNACION,'N')='S'
           AND   B.PROGRAMER_CODE =wprogramer_code
           AND   A.FECHA_HORA_FIN > wfecha2
           AND   A.ROWID <> A.ROWID 
           AND  ( wprimera_fecha BETWEEN  TO_CHAR(A.FECHA_HORA_INICIO,'yyyymm') AND TO_CHAR(A.FECHA_HORA_FIN,'yyyymm')
           OR B.STATUS IN('PAUSADA','EN PROCESO'))
          order by A.FECHA_HORA_INICIO, A.FECHA_HORA_FIN; 

        begin

        for z in c_max_min(wprogramer_code) loop
    
        for  r in  c_horarios(Z.fecha_min,wprogramer_code) loop
            WFECHA_MIN_HORARIO :=R.FECHA;   
            WHORA_MIN_HORARIO  :=R.HORA_INI_M;  
            WFECHA_HORARIOS_MIN :=WFECHA_MIN_HORARIO||' '||WHORA_MIN_HORARIO;
        end loop;
        
        for  f in  c_horarios(Z.fecha_max,wprogramer_code) loop
            WFECHA_MAX_HORARIO :=F.FECHA;   
            WHORA_MAX_HORARIO  :=F.HORA_FIN_T;  
            WFECHA_HORARIOS_MAX :=WFECHA_MAX_HORARIO||' '||WHORA_MAX_HORARIO;       
        end loop;       
        
        end loop;

        OPEN C1;
        FETCH C1 INTO W_ULTIMA_FECHA_INICIO, W_ULTIMA_FECHA_FIN;
          CLOSE C1;


        
      IF  wfecha2 >= TO_DATE(WFECHA_HORARIOS_MIN,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI') AND wprimera_fecha <= TO_DATE(WFECHA_HORARIOS_MAX ,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')THEN 

    IF W_ULTIMA_FECHA_FIN <= TO_DATE(WFECHA_HORARIOS_MIN,'dd-mm-yyyy HH24:MI')  THEN
        WFECHA_INICIO := TO_DATE(WFECHA_HORARIOS_MIN,'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi'); 
    ELSE
        WFECHA_INICIO :=  nvl(W_ULTIMA_FECHA_FIN,TO_DATE(WFECHA_HORARIOS_MIN,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI'));            
    END IF;
    --:CP_TIEMPO_SIN_ORDENES := TO_CHAR(W_ULTIMA_FECHA_FIN,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI');   
            
                
    IF wprimera_fecha >= to_date(WFECHA_HORARIOS_MAX,'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi') THEN
        WFECHA_FIN := TO_DATE(WFECHA_HORARIOS_MAX,'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi'); 
    ELSif wprimera_fecha <= to_date(    WFECHA_HORARIOS_MIN,'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi')THEN
        WFECHA_FIN  :=    TO_DATE(  WFECHA_HORARIOS_MIN,'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi');  
  ELSE
        WFECHA_FIN :=wprimera_fecha ;           
  END IF; 
  
    IF wfecha2 >=  TO_DATE(WFECHA_HORARIOS_MAX,'DD-MM-YYYY hh24:mi')  THEN   
        WFECHA_FIN_ACTUAL := TO_DATE(WFECHA_HORARIOS_MAX,'DD-MM-YYYY hh24:mi');
    ELSE
        WFECHA_FIN_ACTUAL :=wfecha2;
        END IF;
```

> A partir de este bloque es que arroja el error la función *busca_ordenes_pendiente*:

```
IF  wprimera_fecha <>  WFECHA_INICIO THEN
            
            IF  busca_ordenes_pediente(wprogramer_code, WFECHA_INICIO)=0  THEN
                W_HORAS_SIN_ORDENES:= CALCULAR_HORAS_TRAB2(wprogramer_code, WFECHA_INICIO,WFECHA_FIN);
            ELSE    
                W_TOTAL:= CALCULAR_HORAS_TRAB2(wprogramer_code,WFECHA_INICIO,WFECHA_FIN);
            END IF;

      END IF;


        
        open c_busca_max_fercha;
            fetch c_busca_max_fercha into  wmin_max_fecha_mes,wmax_max_fecha_mes;
        close c_busca_max_fercha;
        
        IF  wfecha2 = wmax_max_fecha_mes AND wfecha2 < to_date(WFECHA_MAX_HORARIO||' '||WHORA_MAX_HORARIO,'DD-MM-YYYY hh24:mi') THEN
                IF  busca_ordenes_pediente(wprogramer_code, WFECHA_INICIO)=0  THEN
                    W_HORAS_SIN_ORDENES:= NVL(W_HORAS_SIN_ORDENES,0)+ CALCULAR_HORAS_TRAB2(wprogramer_code,wfecha2,to_date(WFECHA_MAX_HORARIO||' '||WHORA_MAX_HORARIO,'DD-MM-YYYY hh24:mi'));
                ELSE    
                    OPEN C_QUEDAN_ORDENES;
                        FETCH C_QUEDAN_ORDENES INTO  WQUEDAN;
                    CLOSE C_QUEDAN_ORDENES;
                --  IF  WQUEDAN = 0 THEN
                        --  W_HORAS_SIN_ORDENES:= NVL(W_HORAS_SIN_ORDENES,0)+ CALCULAR_HORAS_TRAB2(:PROGRAMER_CODE,:fecha_fin,to_date(WFECHA_MAX_HORARIO||' '||WHORA_MAX_HORARIO,'DD-MM-YYYY hh24:mi'));
                --  ELSE
                            W_TOTAL:=NVL(W_TOTAL,0)+ CALCULAR_HORAS_TRAB2(wprogramer_code,wfecha2,to_date(WFECHA_MAX_HORARIO||' '||WHORA_MAX_HORARIO,'DD-MM-YYYY hh24:mi'));
                --  END IF;
                END IF;

                    
        END IF;
        else
                if W_ULTIMA_FECHA_FIN BETWEEN to_date(WFECHA_HORARIOS_MIN,'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi') AND to_date(WFECHA_HORARIOS_MAX,'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi') then
                    IF  busca_ordenes_pediente(wprogramer_code, W_ULTIMA_FECHA_FIN)=0  THEN
                        W_HORAS_SIN_ORDENES:= CALCULAR_HORAS_TRAB2(wprogramer_code,W_ULTIMA_FECHA_FIN,to_date(WFECHA_HORARIOS_MAX,'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi'));
                    ELSE    
                        W_TOTAL:= CALCULAR_HORAS_TRAB2(wprogramer_code,W_ULTIMA_FECHA_FIN,to_date(WFECHA_HORARIOS_MAX,'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi'));
                    END IF;
                end if;
     END IF;
 
    
    

        /*:CP_HORAS_SIN_ORDENES := W_HORAS_SIN_ORDENES; 
          :CP_TIEMPO_SIN_ORDENES_REAL := CONVERTIR_HORA(W_HORAS_SIN_ORDENES); */
 
     RETURN W_TOTAL;
    end;
```

Comment: Y `busca_ordenes_pediente` está declarado?

Comment: Hola. Bienvenidx a SOes. Por favor no resumas el error. Ponlo completo, con todo y el código PLS. Así como pusiste el código, como texto. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta todas las veces que necesites :) No es claro en el código que ese procedimiento esté declarado ni que se haya compilado sin errores.